# String output by character and output in main

Tags: c, pointers

I tried to make a program that takes string and output it by character and everything were good till. I wanted to try to output the answer in main. Firstly I just tried copy paste it from `form()` to `main()` with little changes but it doesn't work. Thereafter, I have to implement somehow by pointers but none of my attempts were successful. How can I do that? Below is my version with output in form.c

form.h

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char* form(long value);
#endif
```

form.c

```
char* form(long value){
    int a_value = 5; // allocation value
    char *arr; // output array
    arr = (char*) malloc (a_value * sizeof(char));
    int a_buf = a_value; // allocated buffer
    long v = value;
    arr[0] = 43;
    if (v < 0){
        arr[0] = 45;
        v *= -1; // in output, without this, we have numbers with minus
    }
    
    char c = 1; // elements inside array counter
    while (v){
        if (c == a_buf){
            //if all of alloceted memory initializated and we have requirement -> realloc
            a_buf += a_value;
            arr = (char*) realloc(arr, a_buf * sizeof(char));
        }
        arr[c] = v % 10;
        v /= 10;
        c++;
    }

    printf("%d ", arr[0]);
    int i = c - 1;
    for (;i;i--)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    return arr;
}
```

main.c

```
#include "form.h"

int main (){
    long value; //buffer for user value
    scanf("%d", &value);
    char* array = form(value);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", &value);` ==> `scanf("%ld", &value);`.

Comment: Don't hard-code ASCII character codes. Use `'+'` and `'-'` rather than `43` and `45`.

Comment: _I wanted to try to output the answer in main_. How are you trying to print it it `main()`?

Comment: As a general observation, don't `#include` headers where they are not needed - only include them where they are... so the system header files should be included in the .c files

Answer (score 0):

I have your code working in `scanf("% d", & value);`
replaced with `scanf("% ld", & value);` because we are scanning long